# Maximum and minimum logic

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

i came here to find more intuition or understanding to as why does $f''(a)>0$ imply that a is a maximum and $f''(a)<0$ would imply that a is a minimum. Ie. i know that the derivative of a function at a point it's the tangent function, or smth like that.

I'd prefer a visual perspective, for example with y=sin(x), so y'=cos(x) so y''=-sin(x). So from y'=0 we get x=π/2, etc.  So to know if π/2 is a minimum or a maximum, -sen(π/2)<1 so π/2 is a minimum but why? How does this relate to tangents or derivatives or what?

Comment: If $f''(a)>0$ then $f'$ is increasing in an interval around $a$. How does the graph look if the slopes of the tangent lines increase as you move from left to right? It has  a convex shape, right?

Comment: Uh yeah, right?